# JQuery: How to select a class without elements of a parent with id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `ul` element:

```
<ul id="listA">
  <li class="myclass">1</li>
  <li class="myclass">2</li>
  <li class="myclass">3</li>
  <li class="myclass">4</li>
  <li class="myclass">5</li>
  <li>
    <ul id="listB">
      <li class="myclass">B1</li>
      <li class="myclass">B2</li>
      <li class="myclass">B3</li>
      <li class="myclass">B4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get all elements by class name `myclass` which are not in `ul` with ID `listB`.

My tries with `$('.myclass:not ul #listB')` wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not` as follows:

```js
const res = $('*:not(ul#listB) > .myclass');

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="listA">
  <li class="myclass">1</li>
  <li class="myclass">2</li>
  <li class="myclass">3</li>
  <li class="myclass">4</li>
  <li class="myclass">5</li>
  <li>
    <ul id="listB">
      <li class="myclass">B1</li>
      <li class="myclass">B2</li>
      <li class="myclass">B3</li>
      <li class="myclass">B4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh, ok thank you now i see in wich direction i have to create the syntax. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @relo80 you are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('.myclass').not('#listB .myclass')`

```js
$('.myclass').not('#listB .myclass').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listA">
  <li class="myclass">1</li>
  <li class="myclass">2</li>
  <li class="myclass">3</li>
  <li class="myclass">4</li>
  <li class="myclass">5</li>
  <li>
    <ul id="listB">
      <li class="myclass">B1</li>
      <li class="myclass">B2</li>
      <li class="myclass">B3</li>
      <li class="myclass">B4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give more than 1 class names. So give listA class to li which are in listA

```
<ul id="listA">
    <li class="myclass inListA">1</li>
    <li class="myclass inListA">2</li>
    <li class="myclass inListA">3</li>
    <li class="myclass inListA">4</li>
    <li class="myclass inListA">5</li>
    <li>
    <ul id="listB">
    <li class="myclass">B1</li>
    <li class="myclass">B2</li>
    <li class="myclass">B3</li>
    <li class="myclass">B4</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

And now use it like that `$('.inListA')`. It will help I think!